# Recent scifi movie about going to Europa or something

Tags: story-identification, movie

May be some other Jovian moon. Apparently they make some incredible discovery and then the typical Hollywood plot line ensues.

Comment: What is the nature of the discovery, and what is "the typical Hollywood plot line"? Do you know if it's a thriller, mystery, horror, action or drama?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be the movie [Europa Report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_Report)

> Dr. Unger (Embeth Davidtz), CEO of Europa Ventures, narrates the story of the Europa One mission. Six astronauts embark on a privately funded mission to Europa, one of the moons of Jupiter, to find potential sources of life.[3] The crew members are Captain Willam Xu (Daniel Wu), pilot Rosa Dasque (Anamaria Marinca), chief science officer Daniel Luxembourg (Christian Camargo), marine biology science officer Katya Petrovna (Karolina Wydra), junior engineer James Corrigan (Sharlto Copley), and chief engineer Andrei Blok (Michael Nyqvist).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not Europa, then could it be Titan? That would make it Oblivion starring Tom Cruise.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivion_%282013_film%29

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like '2010', the sequel to Kubrick's '2001'.

Comment: 2010 is now almost 30 years old (IMDB has 2014 as release year).  Difficult to categorize that as 'recent scifi movie'.